# What is the best way to run PHP 4 and PHP 5 side-by-side on the same Apache server?

Tags: php

I have a unique requirement where I want to run PHP 4 and PHP 5 on the same web server. How do I acheive it ?

Comment: Good God man, don't run PHP4 anymore. It's been EOL'd for nearly two years now. No updates, no fixes, and no features. Anything still using PHP4-only should be quietly retired and killed.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen shared hosters that use different file extensions to distingush if php 4 or 5 should be used. So they register .php5 for PHP5 and .php for PHP4 in Apache. It is not exactly elegant, but one possibility.

Comment: +1 One of the most common ways of doing it IMO, should require very littly configuration server-side wise

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can run one as an Apache module, the other as cgi.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate on this please.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a lot of conditional code with version checking and take the appropriate step if it is one or the other version something done by the [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) PHP framework.

But first, you will have to know the [differences between php4 and php5](http://www.webmaster-talk.com/php-forum/78717-differences-between-php4-and-php5.html).

You might want to do a startup with a checking version of php:

```
if (version_compare(phpversion(), '4', '>='))
{
  // code.......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run two different versions of PHP with suPHP This documentation is a little outdated - but the approach is the same http://www.howtoforge.com/apache2_suphp_php4_php5 (for instance there are update suPHP builds, and depending on what flavor you deploy on will dictate the sources of your packages)

I love suPHP and use it frequently in most my server builds since it dissolves a lot of user/group issues you find in typical setups.